# Value of limit involving integral of $x/\ln{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I am trying to show that

$$ n\mapsto \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{2}^{n} \frac{x}{\ln{x}}dx $$
converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. It seems to be the case that the integral function of $x/\ln{x}$ cannot be expressed using elementary functions; instead, one can express the integral function using the exponential integral (which I am not familiar with). How could I proceed?

Comment: Think about an easier integral that you know is larger than the one you have.  If the larger integral goes to zero, so will the smaller one.

Comment: Do you know the logarithmic integral function ?

Comment: I actually think that trancelocation's approach is much more concise.  Nevertheless, choosing a bounding integral is not too difficult.  I would use the secant line between $\ln(2)$ and $\ln(n)$ in the denominator, since you know that the log is concave.  If you use this bounding, you get convergence to zero at the same rate of $1/\log(n).$

Comment: Your integrand is increasing and hence less than $n/\log n$ and you can proceed further without much hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider L'Hopital:
$$\frac{1}{t^2} \int_{2}^{t} \frac{x}{\ln{x}}dx\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\sim}\frac{t}{2t\ln t} \stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$